# Differences in event handling in C#

Tags: c#, event-handling

Are there any differences in event handling if in C#? For example if I use different type of project. For example WPF vs WFA, ...

**Edit to be more specific:** 
By **difference** I mean that if I write event handler for some component like buttons, radiobuttons, groupBoxes, ... in some other type of project, that the actual code will not be same. I suppose it shouldn't be.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? `event` and `delegate` in C# work  the same everywhere but what/why/when you use them is dramatically different.

Comment: Event handlers for components generally take different arguments in WPF than they do in Winforms.  A WPF button is a *different object* than a winforms button (System.Windows.Controls.Button vs System.Windows.Forms.Button) so their event handlers are not interchangeable (unless they do not use the event args, in which case the method signature still would need to change).

Answer (score 0):

Yes there differences.  Events are still added and remove the same way, but the events themselves are different.

Read up on RoutedEvents: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx

Comment: So in WPF you need to use some type of XML which is called XAML?
I've never do any application in WPF I only use the WFA and I never need any XAML - I just use the designer of Visual Studio.

Comment: Yes, XAML is an XML format that is a part of WPF. It's just a markup language that generates IL code under the hood.  It is one facet of the WPF stack, others being RoutedEvents and Data Binding.  Those are separate from XAML and can either be used with XAML or without it.